# Xamarin iOS - Tab Page - Move Icon Postitions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, icons

I have a tab page in my app, on android it looks great - the icons are entered (no text, just icon) and look nice.

On iOS, my tab bar is at the bottom (that's fine) but the icons are pressed RIGHT up against the top of the tab bar. So there is tons of space below them, but they are on the edge at the top. Well at least 2 of them are. The other 2 have image padding built in for a couple pixels because of the image designs and are a touch lower. But that's beside the point.

How on iOS only can I set some padding on the tab-page icons? or centre them?

[image]

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom renderer to center the icon.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.iOS
{
    class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            var tabBarItems = TabBar.Items;
            tabBarItems[0].ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(6, 0, -6, 0);

            tabBarItems[1].ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(6, 0, -6, 0);
            tabBarItems[2].ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(6, 0, -6, 0);

        }
    }
}
```